# Как перегрузить функцию find библиотеки <set> в С++?

Tags: c++

Привет, ситуация следующая: мне нужно множество матриц, для чего я создал объект matrix, который хранит свойством массив [3][3] (если можно в set запихнуть массив, отпишитесь ниже, как). Функция find для таких объектов не работает корректно (т.е. мне надо найти матрицу, индентичную данной в set (объект, который хранит идентичный массив), но find пропускает идентичные массивы, потому что никто ведь не додумался бы так их хранить и тем более обучать find искать их правильно) можно ли её переопределить?
Запись вида

```
bool set<matrix>::find(const matrix a) {
  //перегрузка
}
```

подчеркивает `find` и выдает ошибку "использование унаследованных членов не допускается.
При переходе на подсказку и нажатии на *"создать объявление "find" в set"* появляется это,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

что естественно. Но мне всё ещё надо перегрузить этот `find`, так что жду предложений.

P. S. Перегрузка:

```
bool operator == (const matrix &left, const matrix &right) {
    bool res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < base; j++) {
            if (left.a[i][j] != right.a[i][j]) {
                res = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}  

bool operator < (const matrix &left, const matrix &right) {
    bool res = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < base; j++) {
            if (left.a[i][j] >= right.a[i][j]) {
                res = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!res) {
        int sumLeft = 0;
        int sumRight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < base; j++) {
                sumLeft += left.a[i][j];
                sumRight += right.a[i][j];
            }
        }
        if (sumLeft < sumRight) {
            res = true;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Пример некорректной работы (в выводе - *"out"*):

```
int e[3][3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (i == j) {
            e[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else {
            e[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
set<matrix> elems;
matrix temp;
matrix temp1;
memcpy(temp.a, e, sizeof(temp.a));
memcpy(temp1.a, e, sizeof(temp1.a));
elems.insert(temp);
if (elems.find(temp1) != elems.end()) {
    cout << "in";
}
else {
    cout << "out";
}
```

После исправлений из ответов ниже выкидывает *invalid comparator*, когда данной матрицы нет в множестве. Я подозреваю, что set не может сравнить matrix с set.end(). Как можно это решить?
последнее приложение:

```
class matrix {
public:
    int a[3][3];
    matrix() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                a[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};


//________________________________________________________________

bool operator < (const matrix &left, const matrix &right) {
    bool res = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (left.a[i][j] != right.a[i][j]) {
                res = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Создать класс, отнаследованный от `std::set` и перегрузить функцию `find` внутри. Либо определить `operator==` и `operator<` в классе `matrix` так, как вам нужно.

Comment: Нужно перегрузить `operator <` для класса matrix. Тогда вас устроит стандартная реализация set::find.

Comment: @MrBin почему как в `operator <`, а не `operator ==`?

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko, [Вот хорошее объяснение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287224/why-isnt-stdfind-using-my-operator).

Comment: @Ternvein, Никогда не наследуйте стандартные контейнеры и другим не советуйте. У них нет виртуального деструктора. Отличная почва для того, чтобы выстрелить себе в ногу

Comment: @Ternvein, и `operator==` для `std::set` не нужен. Любую операцию сравнения можно получить через `<`, что `std::set` и делает. Равенство так `!(x < y) && !(y < x)`

Comment: @SimonGerasimenko, комитет стандартизации с++ уже работает над оператором летающей тарелки aka spaceship operator aka `operator<=>`. В будущем надо будет только его определить, остальное компилятор сам сгенерирует. Но это не раньше c++23

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, очень спорное утверждение про наследование. Невиртуальный деструктор означает, что будут проблемы при попытках освобождения объекта через указатель на базовый класс. Это большой минус, но при `private` наследовании это не имеет значения, т.к. указатель на базовый класс взять не получится. Единственное, что пострадает при наследовании, это изменение ABI при изменении имплементации класса.
Также некоторые контейнеры, например `std::stack`, имеют `protected` члены, что недвусмысленно намекает на предусмотренность наследования.

Comment: @Ternvein, а я и не говорил что это ошибка. Я сказал что  это почва для ошибок. Можно, конечно, жонглировать бензопилами, но зачем?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71530/discussion-on-question-by-simon-gerasimenko----find-).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
struct Matrix{
    static constexpr int base = 5;
    int a[base][base];
};

bool operator<(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    for(int line = 0; line < Matrix::base; ++line){
        for(int column = 0; column < Matrix::base; ++column){
            if(left.a[line][column] != right.a[line][column]){
                return left.a[line][column] < right.a[line][column];
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Матрицы сравниваются по первому различающемуся элементу.

Если надо, можно и остальные операторы вывести:

```
bool operator>(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    return right < left;
}

bool operator==(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    return !(left < right) && !(left > right);
}

bool operator!=(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    return !(left == right);
}

bool operator>=(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    return !(left < right);
}

bool operator<=(const Matrix &left, const Matrix &right){
    return !(left > right);
}
```

**UPD** Ошибка *invalid comparator* возникает тогда, когда ваш `operator<()` не соответствует правилам [строгого слабого упорядочения](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare). Проверить это можно так:

```
Matrix a;
a.a[1][0] = 1;

Matrix b;
b.a[0][1] = 1;

Matrix c;
c.a[0][1] = 2;

//false
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a < a) << std::endl;
//true false
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a < b) << " " << (b < a) << std::endl;
//true true true 
std::cout << std::boolalpha << (a < b) << " " << (b < c) << " " << (a < c) << std::endl;
```

http://rextester.com/YHJED27691

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71529/discussion-on-answer-by-yrhetatejlb----find--set).

Answer (score 0):

У тебя неверный `operator <`, а `operator ==` вообще не нужен.

Надо так:

```
bool operator < (const matrix &left, const matrix &right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < base; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < base; j++) {
            if (left.a[i][j] != right.a[i][j]) {
                return left.a[i][j] < right.a[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Должно быть верно, что `a == b` тогда и только тогда, когда `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`.

Comment: Это тоже неправильная реализация. 
Для нее матрицы {{1,0,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}}  и {{0,1,0},{0,0,0},{0,0,0}} - равны.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение принципа сравнения с помощью `<` сейчас попробую что-нибудь с этим сделать

Comment: @Chorkov, согласен, исправил.

Comment: @Qwertiy, теперь у вас `x < x` дает `true`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, ой.. исправил.